# UDP and Threads - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, udp

I'm using UDP to communicate through threads, but I want to make some kind of variable to know if the thread waiting for a message has waited too long.

Is there any method inherited by UDP class that I could use?
Or is it a better choice to make my own timekeeper parallel to every thread to keep the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question: If a thread has waited too long for a message, what should it do?

Answer: Stop waiting!

What you should probably do is to call [`setSoTimeout(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setSoTimeout-int-) on the `DatagramSocket` to set a timeout before you call `receive(DatagramPacket)`.  This will cause the thread that is waiting for a message to get a `SocketTimeoutException` if it waits for longer than the timeout.

---

To answer your actual question:

- There isn't a builtin method that one method can call to see how long another thread has been waiting for a message.
- Building a separate timekeeper is possible but rather heavy-weight

Comment: Thank you! I didn't read UDP's documentation thoroughly. Netbeans throwed all kinds of autocompletion for methods and I didn't notice it had a timeout. I think that will do it. :)